# setting Adobe Acrobat as the default with registry

Tags: windows-registry

Just looking for registry entries that I can set Adobe Reader as the default and to change from Edge. I was hoping not to create an XML script and create a new GPO. Just figured that the registry could be changed to default Adobe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Should be as simple, setting the default application, then exporting the appropriate registry key and importing it.

Comment: You can set the default handler by using the properties on a .PDF file and assigning the default application for the file extension.

Comment: I am looking to set registry entries that I can push down with a GPO. This way, everyone will log into their computers and the Adobe will be set as default instead of Edge. I have roaming users that share about 12 computers so this is why I'm doing this. Also, I'd like to do the same with Chrome, set it as default instead of Edge.